# IF statement not working as I expected

Tags: vb.net

Hi so im playing with microsoft visual studio 2010 edition and I need to make an if statement work on it.

What im doing is putting a number into a textbox, it then goes into my listbox (however many times I put numbers in like 3-4 numbers). Then it is meant to add them all up and put it into the label after.

Heres the program so far

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim Result As Integer
        For Each Item As Integer In ListBox1.Items
            Result = Result + Item
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Value As String
        Value = TextBox1.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Value)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Label1.Text = "You have a Balance of " + DialogResult.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If (String.a
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you intend to happen inside the `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler? Can you at least put in some pseudo-code?

Comment: Im not sure I was trying to see if a string would work there. I just want the listbox to add all the numbers I put in there and then when I click calculate be put in the label

Comment: Is it about C# or VB.net?

Comment: Please take the time to name your controls and variables properly.  Names like Button1, Label1, and TextBox1 give absolutely no clue as to what they are used for.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic .NET (which is what your code looks to be in), `If` statements are formatted like this:

`If condition Then
    DoSomeCodeHere()
End If`

C# code is formatted as

```
if (condition) 
{
  DoSomeCodeHere();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wan the sum all the amount in the list box and show it in a label after clicking button 2?
If yes add the below should do.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Result As Integer
    For Each Item As Integer In ListBox1.Items
        Result = Result + Item
    Next
    Label1.Text = "You have a Balance of " + Result.ToString
 End Sub
```